# Using logs to solve an inequality

Tags: inequality, logarithms

When I use a natural log to solve $5000 (0.88)^{(n-1)}$ < $100$ 
I get the correct answer $n > 31.6$ so $n = 32$
But when I use log to the Base $0.88$ I get $n < 31.6$ 
The inequality sign is incorrect, why?

Comment: Can you show us your work. We can't point out where you went wrong without seeing what you did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $\log_{0.88}$ is not what you think it is *(in short: it is a decreasing function, not increasing as $\log_2,\log_{10}$ are)*. The base $b$ of a logarithm must be a positive number different than $1$, and then we have

$$
\log_b x = \frac{\ln x}{\ln b}
$$
where $\ln$ denotes the natural logarithm (base $e$). (Cf. e.g. the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Change_of_base).)

Now, observe that for $b=0.88$, we have $\ln b < 0$ (since $b\in(0,1)$). So, when you get (solving the inequality)
$$
(n-1) < \log_{0.88}\frac{100}{5000}
$$
you should see that you applied the function $\log_{0.88}=\frac{\ln}{\ln 0.88}$ to both sides of the original inequality, and this function $\log_{0.88}$ is a **decreasing** function (since $\ln$ is increasing). You should have switched the sign of the inequality.

*(Indeed, if $f$ is a decreasing function, then $a< b$ is equivalent to $f(a)>f(b)$: the sign only remains the same for increasing functions.)*

Comment: My advice is: unless someone requires you to do so at gunpoint, do *not* use logarithms with base smaller than $1$. They will, most likely, not behave like you expect them to, and it's hard to track down where the error occurs.

Comment: So when solving I will avoid this error if I always use a natural log?!

Comment: @Cliona Yes, natural is a good choice (or, if you are in a computer science setting where powers of $2$ abound, the binary logarithm $\log_2$ may be good as well).

Answer (score 1):

$\log_a x = \frac {\ln x}{\ln a}$
and if $a<1, \ln a < 0$

When you take the log in base $0.88$ you are effectively dividing by a negative number, and that flips the direction of your inequalities.